# how to manage the session in tomcat load balancing?

Tags: java, session, tomcat

we have load balancing for the java application.but how to manage the session. Like if user logged in and he has entered in the application.and the server which is processed the requests,has been down somehow then in load balancing load will transfer to other server.but wat happened to those who already logged into application.how we will pass the same session to the server.
Please help me to get rid this problem with an example.

Comment: what have you tried so for please edit question with the code you are currently using to fix this issue

Comment: we added this configuration in apache httpd.xml   <Proxy balancer://testcluster stickysession=JSESSIONID>
BalancerMember ajp://127.0.0.1:8009 min=10 max=100 route=node1 loadfactor=1
BalancerMember ajp://127.0.0.1:8019 min=20 max=200 route=node2 loadfactor=2

</Proxy>

ProxyPass /jarolInvestmentsGames balancer://testcluster/applicationname stickysession=JSESSIONID
ProxyPassReverse /applicationname balancer://testcluster/applicationname stickysession=JSESSIONID
#ProxyPass /applicationname balancer://testcluster/applicationname

Comment: You can serialize/deserialize the user's session if he is logged in or not.

Comment: In tomcat node i added whole config and also added </distributable> tag into web.xml in web app root folder for both tomcat node--

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is called [session replication](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/cluster-howto.html).

Comment: yes correct ...but mugging up in session..!! i have done all configuration .dont know where am i doing mistake . i did exactly the same as in the doc